# air process adt flex

Tags: air

I have two air applications and installed them in desktop and executed them and two air processes are listed in taskbar manager.Now how can I execute some method of one air application from another air application?

Comment: Did that answer help you out?

Answer (score 3):

Use [LocalConnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/LocalConnection.html).

You can Host a Connection in one AIR application and connect from the the other AIR guy... From there - you can call methods.

BEWARE: LocalConnection can be a little tricky and odd (for example, connections are global and the names can't overlap).

From the Example Doc listed above....

```
// Code in LocalConnectionSenderExample.as
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.LocalConnection;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.events.StatusEvent;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class LocalConnectionSenderExample extends Sprite {
        private var conn:LocalConnection;

        // UI elements
        private var messageLabel:TextField;
        private var message:TextField;
        private var sendBtn:Sprite;

        public function LocalConnectionSenderExample() {
            buildUI();
            sendBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendMessage);
            conn = new LocalConnection();
            conn.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onStatus);
        }

        private function sendMessage(event:MouseEvent):void {
            conn.send("myConnection", "lcHandler", message.text);
        }

        private function onStatus(event:StatusEvent):void {
            switch (event.level) {
                case "status":
                    trace("LocalConnection.send() succeeded");
                    break;
                case "error":
                    trace("LocalConnection.send() failed");
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function buildUI():void {
            const hPadding:uint = 5;
            // messageLabel
            messageLabel = new TextField();
            messageLabel.x = 10;
            messageLabel.y = 10;
            messageLabel.text = "Text to send:";
            messageLabel.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            addChild(messageLabel);

            // message
            message = new TextField();
            message.x = messageLabel.x + messageLabel.width + hPadding;
            message.y = 10;
            message.width = 120;
            message.height = 20;
            message.background = true;
            message.border = true;
            message.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            addChild(message);

            // sendBtn
            sendBtn = new Sprite();
            sendBtn.x = message.x + message.width + hPadding;
            sendBtn.y = 10;
            var sendLbl:TextField = new TextField();
            sendLbl.x = 1 + hPadding;
            sendLbl.y = 1;
            sendLbl.selectable = false;
            sendLbl.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            sendLbl.text = "Send";
            sendBtn.addChild(sendLbl);
            sendBtn.graphics.lineStyle(1);
            sendBtn.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc);
            sendBtn.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 
(sendLbl.width + 2 + hPadding + hPadding), (sendLbl.height + 2), 5, 5);
            sendBtn.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(sendBtn);
        }
    }
}


// Code in LocalConnectionReceiverExample.as
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.LocalConnection;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class LocalConnectionReceiverExample extends Sprite {
        private var conn:LocalConnection;
        private var output:TextField;

        public function LocalConnectionReceiverExample()     {
            buildUI();

            conn = new LocalConnection();
            conn.client = this;
            try {
                conn.connect("myConnection");
            } catch (error:ArgumentError) {
                trace("Can't connect...the connection name is already 
being used by another SWF");
            }
        }

        public function lcHandler(msg:String):void {
            output.appendText(msg + "\n");
        }

        private function buildUI():void {
            output = new TextField();
            output.background = true;
            output.border = true;
            output.wordWrap = true;
            addChild(output);
        }
    }
}
```